# DOJO drop down selection is not working

Tags: dojo

After migrating to DOJO 1.8.14 in the dropdown even though I am selecting different one it is selecting by default different option than that is present before.

You can see the dropdown after close button that should select different one and also one more issue is few functionalities are working in IE browser and not working in the mozila firefox browser

[image: You can see the dropdown after close button]

Someone help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In code it had return to sort by label and the particular element is disabled so it is not selecting once after I had added sortbylabel id as false and then it is working fine.

The problem is DOJO migration that I had done will sort the label by default we need to apply the label to false then it will work fine.